# How can I add a prompt to my Python port scanner that asks users to enter what ports they want scanned?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help adding in a function to my Port Scanner that asks the user to input what ports they want scanned and displays only the ports they asked for, this is my current code:

```
# importing libraries we want to use
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# prompt user to input the Target IP
target = input("[+] Enter Target IP: ")

#define the scanner function and try to connect to the target IP and port
def scanner(port):
  try:
    sock.connect((target, port))
    return True
  except:
    return False

#use for loop to state what ports are getting scanned, use scanner function to try and make a connection 
try:
  for portNumber in inclusiverange(1,100 + 1):
    print("scanning port", portNumber)
    if scanner(portNumber ):
      print('[*] Port', portNumber, '/tcp', 'is open')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the same way, you asked for target IP. You can expect user to enter multiple ports, and then you iterate over them to give the required output.
Following code represents, what I'm trying to say.

```
# importing libraries we want to use
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# prompt user to input the Target IP
target = input("[+] Enter Target IP: ")

#define the scanner function and try to connect to the target IP and port
def scanner(port):
  try:
    sock.connect((target, port))
    return True
  except:
    return False

# Asking the user for the ports that they want to be scanned  
ports = input("Enter the ports to be scanned: ")    # User can enter as 100 122 123
ports_list = ports.split(' ')   # Splitting user input to get all the ports

#use for loop to state what ports are getting scanned, use scanner function to try and make a connection
try:
  for portNumber in ports_list:
    print("scanning port", portNumber)
    if scanner(portNumber ):
      print('[*] Port', portNumber, '/tcp', 'is open')
finally:
    pass
```